# My measure doesn`t work in case of date filters

Tags: powerbi, dax

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yt6cw.png)I have daily values of closing balances of balance sheet. I want to have a measure which calculates the percentage change between two dates. The issue is that on weekdays the values are empty. So I have written the following measure which works when there are no filters, but when I place a date filter, the values of the measure become zeros.

```
Change_BS %(daily) =
IF (
    SUM ( 'DB Daily_BS'[Value] ) = 0,
    0,
    IF (
        SUM ( 'Date'[Weekday] ) = 1,
        DIVIDE (
            SUM ( 'DB Daily_BS'[Value] )
                - CALCULATE ( SUM ( 'DB Daily_BS'[Value] ), DATEADD ( 'Date'[Date], -3, DAY ) ),
            CALCULATE ( SUM ( 'DB Daily_BS'[Value] ), DATEADD ( 'Date'[Date], -3, DAY ) )
        ),
        DIVIDE (
            SUM ( 'DB Daily_BS'[Value] )
                - CALCULATE ( SUM ( 'DB Daily_BS'[Value] ), PREVIOUSDAY ( 'Date'[Date] ) ),
            CALCULATE ( SUM ( 'DB Daily_BS'[Value] ), PREVIOUSDAY ( 'Date'[Date] ) )
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: I would go with a column calculating the difference of the previous data. This will not be impacted by filters.

Comment: OK, and could you help me with creating a column of difference of the previous data?

Comment: I can, can you add a little axample of your table with relevant comumns and some data, like 1 rows. I also need to mention that I do not have time today, tomorrow I can spend some time on it.

Comment: Of course. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

de a new Column called BS_Value which fills in the gaps for the weekends.

```
BS_Value = 
var wday = MOD(WEEKDAY(Balance[Date]);7)
var daysBack = IF(wday < 2; wday + 1)
return CALCULATE(SUM(Balance[Value]);Balance[Date]  = EARLIER(Balance[Date]) - daysBack)
```

Based on this column I made BS-Change what is the increment/decrement form previous:

```
BS_Change = Balance[BS_Value] - CALCULATE(SUM(Balance[BS_Value]);Balance[Date] = EARLIER(Balance[Date]) - 1)
```

End result:

[image]

You can now make measures or other columns based on those values. I need to say a more dynamic solution is possible where we would go for a lookup of the last value not zero. I did not do this because I can imagine the balance is zero and it would then skip those values.

Comment: Thanks for spending time on my problem. But I got zeroes on the calculated column BS_Value.

Comment: I get the same values on both these two columns

Comment: 1. WEEKDAY('DB Daily_BS'[Date])

Comment: 2. WEEKDAY('DB Daily_BS'[Date])

Comment: It is not clear to me wht youhave been doing and what the columns are you are talking about..

Comment: The values are daily closing balances of balance sheet items. The issue is that the system does not generate values on weekdays and holidays. I want to create balance sheet statement with the daily percentage changes.

Comment: Yes, and if you look at my solution you can see I replaced the value zero for the weekend so the balance stays same. I created a column showing the difference with previous day do with this you should be able to calc your percentage change?